# Making a replacement on the numerator and denominator of a rational number

Tags: pattern-matching, number-representation

It's isn't a big deal, but when I run the following I don't get the output I expect.  After discussing this in the comments it appears it has to do with being an atomic expression.

```
FullForm @ Replace[
 Rational[1, 2], {
  x_Integer :> a[x]
  },
 {0, Infinity}
 ]
```

Here is a a solution I have worked out:

```
FullForm @ Replace[
  Rational[1, 2], {
   x_Integer :> a[x],
   Rational[x_Integer, b_Integer] :> Rational[a @ x, a @ b]
   },
  {0, Infinity}
  ]
```

Is there a better solution?

Comment: Not the downvoter but I think the issue here with trying to use `Replace` on the `Rational` is that a `Rational` is atomic (`Depth` of 1) so the `Replace` is not going to examine the numerator or denominator of the `Rational`, regardless of the levels you specify. It only sees the rational as a whole.

Comment: @It'sPronouncedOiler It doesn't look like it is a bug, what is the best fix?

Comment: Well I always hate to give the answer that the solution you're unsatisfied with is the best one, but that seems to be the case here. To me, it seems without specifying the `Rational` in the pattern that MMA doesn't have access to the deeper elements of the number (the numerator and denominator) , even though we know it's comprised of as many as 2 integer numbers. I noted the same behavior if you try to do it with `Complex` instead of `Rational`, which MMA also treats as atomic. We know the `Complex` is comprised of 2 `Reals` but w/o a similar pattern, MMA won't access them.

Comment: How about `Hold[Rational[1, 2]] /. x_Integer :> a[x] // ReleaseHold` ?

Comment: Your desired replacement could be done inside `Hold`, before `Rational` has had a chance to evaluate and become atomic.

Comment: @William Deleting your comment, after it's been replied to, makes other people look like they are talking to themselves, no?

Comment: @ilian I don't do it regularly, but your comment was deleted seconds of mine so I didn't both responding, otherwise I was going to post a thanks saying I believe I understood now.

Comment: @William I don't understand. None of my comments have been deleted.

Comment: @ilian The original comment is no longer their. It was someone else Albert Retey `@William: sorry, I'm also not fluid concerning CSS selectors but am somewhat surprised that t...`.  That is why I'm confused.  I don't believe I'm sure what comment I deleted.

Comment: @ilian I'm sory I would undo it if I could.  Do you know what the original comment said. I'll edit the post above so you don't look  misinterpreted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way to deconstruct `Rational` is to use `Numerator` and `Denominator`:

```
Replace[Rational[1, 2], {x_Rational :> Rational[a@ Numerator@x, a@ Denominator@x]}]
(*  Rational[a[1], a[2]]  *)
```

Or perhaps a fraction is desired:

```
Replace[Rational[1, 2], {x_Rational :> a@ Numerator@x / a@ Denominator@x}]
(*  a[1]/a[2]  *)
```

While it might be considered by some to be more expressive than the OP's replacement `Rational[x_Integer, b_Integer] :> Rational[a@x, a@b]`, it is also slightly slower (roughly 1 second per 10^6 rational numbers).

The same sort of thing can be done with the atomic `Complex`:

```
Replace[Complex[1, 2], {x_Complex :> Complex[a@ Re@x, a@ Im@x]}]
(*  Complex[a[1], a[2]]  *)

Replace[Complex[1, 2], {x_Complex :> a@ Re@x + a@ Im@x * I}]
(*  a[1] + I a[2]  *)
```

---

Note: I don't believe there's anything wrong with `Rational[a[1], a[2]]`, but it is not atomic.  It also does not behave as a number or an algebraic fraction in expressions.  It seems to be an expression on its way to being a rational number, as soon as the values of `a[1]` and `a[2]` become integers, unless `a[2]` becomes `0`.  It is similar with `Complex[a[1], a[2]]`.

Answer (score 4):

A better solution is the one given by ilian in the comments. For example,

```
a[1] = 5; a[2] = 42;
Hold[Rational[1, 2]] /. x_Integer :> a[x] // ReleaseHold
```

> ```
> 5/42
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Based on what I guess (by reading the comments and edit history) OP is trying to accomplish, it may also be done with the `Box` way:

```
Rational[1, 2] //
   MakeBoxes //
  # /. x_String /; StringMatchQ[x, DigitCharacter ..] :> 
     RowBox[{"a", "[", x, "]"}] & //
 MakeExpression
```